# Is it unprofessional to listen to music while at work?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, distractions

Even with headphones on with the volume on low, would this still be considered rude or unprofessional? I'd like to listen to music to help me get through my work but don't want to get told off for it.

My office can be fairly noisy but on other occasions it's quiet. Should I only be using my headphones for work-related things such as taking a business call?

Comment: Let's imagine the future. Suppose you get a load of answers saying "Yes, it's entirely professional to wear headphones." You go ahead and wear headphones. Your supervisor tells you to stop. What are you going to do, say "But a load of *people from the internet* said it was OK!!?!?" ? No. **Ask your supervisor**.

Comment: @AakashM Is this not workplace.stackexchange.com? How different is it from asking any other questions relating to professionalism in the workplace? I'd like to know.

Comment: [Related]http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/how-can-i-make-wearing-headphones-at-work-more-acceptable

Comment: He didn't ask if it's against his employer's policy, he asked if it's considered rude or unprofessional.  The implication being "generally speaking..." etc.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta Workplace SE](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2903/98), the site for discussing site policies and, in general, how Workplace SE functions.

Comment: Note that you can typically have the music much lower if you use noise-cancelling headphones.

Comment: Note that you can play the music much louder without disturbing anyone if you use the right noise-cancelling headphones :-) I asked my colleagues, and they say that they cannot _hear_ music that I'm playing even if I turn it uncomfortably loud.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on your position.

In my case, I tend to listen to music or even the radio, because I'm in IT, but people in customer service or other partners can't, as they need to be really concentrated on what they write in emails or what they say.

In our case, it's fine to listen to music, I personally use Grooveshark, and others use Spotify, but anyway it's rude if you listen to music so loud you cannot hear if someone asks you for help.

My trick is to leave one ear out of the headphones, so I can hear if people talk to me.

However, if it's really noisy, put on your headphones and only listen to music without lyrics, a little low. That way, you can concentrate on your work (because there's music in the foreground and the background sound is not heard anymore), yet any voice around you will be pretty easy for you to notice.

My golden trick:

**Ask around if anybody listens to music. If nobody does, check if they listened to music before, and this was banned.**

Comment: Grooveshark and Spotify will add the issue of bandwidth.

Comment: @borjab it depends on what device you are using to do the listening. Also, many workplace "Acceptable Use Policies" would allow this, so long as the usage does not impact the performance of business systems.

Comment: I agree.  I work in IT, and although I've never done this personally, half of the people I work with (including my supervisor) keep headphones in their ears all the time.  But as soon as you step up to them to ask them something, they all seem to notice you right off the bat, so it's not like they're distracted.  As a matter of fact, it's been demonstrated that at least muzak (elevator music) has a tendancy to make people work faster.

Comment: How does "need to concentrate on what they write in emails" jive with "shouldn't wear headphones"? If anything, if they need to concentrate on what they write, they should do whatever they can do reduce distractions. Chances are, some music that drowns out sales calls, other typers and office chatter will provide a concentration boost.

Comment: Well @corsiKa, good point, at least in my case, when I need to write a technical email, I may keep my music low (I tend to listen indie and rock, with strong lyrics), because otherwise I try to follow the song at the same time. However, when coding, following the music allows me to concentrate. I guess it depends on each other, I admit it was more like a personal comment.

However, none of our customer service consultant keeps her headphones on, ever. Only for phonecalls (and that's without music, obviously) and when doing tasks other than talking to clients

Comment: Customer service staff have to concentrate so hard that they can't listen to background music, but IT staff don't? What kind of work is your IT staff doing that it requires less concentration than writing an email? In many modern "open office" floor plans, the *only* way to concentrate on work is to block out the office noise with headphones and music. Even with a noise masking system in the office, I can hear conversations 40 feet away.

Comment: _Absolutely, @Johnny, we never do anything, we just eat Cheetos the whole day while listening to music and playing games_. Nah, I understand your point. However, as an IT, I'm sure you can make mistakes, as you'll be testing everything (if you never make a mistake, **check your code again**). If you write "300" instead of "3000", you may notice that while running the tests. As a CS, if they wrote down 300€ instead of 3000€, an evil customer would be able to get something worth 3000€ for 300€. Your reasoning is valid. But you could wear protection headsets, if that's your only issue.

Comment: Do not leave an ear off the speaker. This is unhealthy as in the long term may cause hearing imbalance. And a headache in the short term

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ thanks for your suggestion. I've had the luck to never have a headache (at least not of having an ear off), but surely in the long term it could be a serious problem

Answer (score 7):

> Even with headphones on with the volume on low, would this still be
>   considered rude or unprofessional?

As always, it depends.

There are many contexts in which it might not be appropriate to wear headphones at work:

- Your company or boss prohibits them
- You work in a service position, where customers need to talk with you
- You must answer the telephone frequently
- You must answer frequent questions from others in your office
- An environment where wearing headphones would be a safety concern
- etc, etc

You best bet is to specifically ask your boss "Is it okay if I wear headphones?" Then you will know for sure.

If that isn't feasible, you could look around and see if your coworkers are wearing them, or just ask others in your office if this is acceptable.

Absent that, one approach would be to wear them and see if anyone complains.

Comment: You had me until the last sentence.  I would much, much rather be asked than have to deal with a problem after it happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general principle at work here. You want to have a constructive, open, relationship with your supervisor. Your supervisor should be your first port of call in navigating your employer's culture. If you are unsure if headphones are culturally acceptable, *ask*! And the same goes for sandals, pictures of your cat on your desk, and anything else. If your supervisor is a troll of some kind, you have a more complex problem than headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the real deal. It all depends on the degree to which you need to communicate with others.

If you work a help-desk and are answering phones all day, no, listening to music at your desk is a bad idea.

If you are a "heads-down" developer, listening to music may actually make you a better developer coming up with more [creative](http://copywritersroundtable.com/2014/07/18/can-music-make-you-more-creative/) solutions. Here, your interactions with other people are limited.

Now, if you have a boss that demands you never listen to music (probably because he/she grew up in a town where they banned dancing a-la [Footloose](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087277/plotsummary)), then don't listen to music.

- Don't listen to music in your office without [headphones](http://www.beatsbydre.com/).
- Don't listen to [music at high volumes](http://www.metallica.com/), even if you are wearing headphones.
- Don't walk-around the office with your headphones in jamming-out,
  people will think you look like a [douche](http://www.blursto.com/all/In-Defense-of-the-Hipster--103).

Finally, if someone comes up to you to interact socially or professionally, follow these [steps to be cool](http://www.wikihow.com/Be-Cool):

1. Turn off the music,
2. Take off your headphones,
3. [Listen actively.](http://www.mindtools.com/CommSkll/ActiveListening.htm)

Once you do all this, you'll get [IRL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IRL) [XP](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864971765401422666/), and [Level-up](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2011/03/03/game-of-life/)!

Answer (score 0):

The key criterion to use in deciding whether it's OK to play the music is the impact on your work and the work of others:

If nobody but you can hear the music you're playing, why should they care as long as the work gets done?

Playing the muzak is unprofessional if it gets in the way of your own work or  the work of others.

If no one is complaining, then your playing of your music is not getting in the way of anyone's work. Once, I did try to get away with playing the music so loud that I couldn't hear anyone complain. The long and short of it, mostly short, is that I didn't get away with it :)